# My promise is resolving before I think it should

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I am trying to use q promises to handle some long-running ajax requests and subsequent data processing.  I have a case where I am trying to create some promises that should be executed in sequence, but they seem to be resolving before I want them to and I'm not sure why.

The main sequence is to first try some "main" work which should be done asynchronously, then do some "follow-up" work which itself comprises a set of several async requests.  Here's the main body from my fiddle which demos the problem:

```
var to_do = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];
var result = Q();
to_do.forEach(function (item) {
  result = result
    .then(dowork.bind(null, item))
    .fail(handleError)
    .then(dofollowup.bind(null, item));
});

var dowork = function (value) {
  var deferred = Q.defer();
  log("About to do main work for " + value);
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (value === 'two') {
      // represent a possible error in this work, but we still need to do follow-up work
      deferred.reject("An error occurred doing work for number two, but we should continue");
    } else {
      log("Done main work for " + value);
      deferred.resolve(value);    
    }
  }, 1000);
  return deferred.promise;
}

var dofollowup = function (value) {
  log("Doing follow-up work for " + value);
  var to_do = Q();
  for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    to_do = to_do.then(function () {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      setTimeout(function () {
        log("Doing delayed work for " + value);
        deferred.resolve();
      }, 100);
    });
  }
  return to_do;
}
```

My immediate problem is that the "main" work for the next item is being started before the "follow-up" work for an item is finished.  I am guessing I'm just not dealing with the promises correctly and accidentally resolving it too soon, but I don't see how at the moment.

I created a fiddle that simulates my problem.  In it, I see the work for the "two" work item starting before the follow-up for "one" is complete.  How can I insure that I complete each item's follow-up before starting on the main work for the next?

https://jsfiddle.net/cfarmerga/cp323djx/1/

[image]

Comment: You forgot to return your deferred promise in your dofollowup..  IOW: you created a deferred but never returned it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying your dofollowup to return the deferred seems to fix this.

```
var dofollowup = function (value) {

  log("Doing follow-up work for " + value);

  var to_do = Q();
  for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    to_do = to_do.then(function () {
      var deferred = Q.defer();
      setTimeout(function () {
        log("Doing delayed work for " + value);
        deferred.resolve();
      }, 100);
      return deferred.promise; //you forgot this..
    });
  }
  return to_do;

}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks.  This is definitely the cause of the issue in my fiddle.  This seems obvious now, but unfortunately now it doesn't seem to mimic my main app that's failing.  Maybe I'm forgetting to return the promise from one of my chained functions like this.  Back to the digging!